# How to stop audio from playing when the notification is clicked in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, audio, notifications

i have this Notification function that display notification on specific time and play an audio (2-3 mins audio)

how is it possible to stop the audio if the user clicked the notification?

```
private fun sendNotification(nextPray: Pray) {
    createNotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID2)
    log("Send Notification")
    //small view
    val collapsedView = RemoteViews(
        packageName,
        R.layout.notification_collapsed
    )
    //big view
    val expandedView = RemoteViews(
        packageName,
        R.layout.notification_expanded
    )
    val snoozeIntent = Intent(this, StopAlarm::class.java)
    val snoozePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, snoozeIntent, 0)
    val notificationIntent = Intent(this, FullAzan::class.java)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0)
    expandedView.setTextViewText(R.id.text_view_collapsed_2, "Muazzin - ${nextPray.moazin}");
    val mBuilder: NotificationCompat.Builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID2)

            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.qalby_ic)
            .setContentTitle("Tap to get the full Azan")
            .setContentText("Muazzin - ${nextPray.moazin}")
            .setCustomContentView(collapsedView)
            .setCustomBigContentView(expandedView)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .addAction(
                R.drawable.ic_stop,
                getString(R.string.text_stop),
                snoozePendingIntent
            )
            .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID2)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
    stopSelf()
    val notification = mBuilder.build()
    notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)
    notificationManager.notify(100, notification)
    //startForeground(100, notification)
    log("vibrating")
    vibrate()
    log("Azan Audio Started")
    MediaPlayerManager.getInstance(applicationContext).azan(nextPray)
}
```

as you can see i tried to do that by adding:

```
.setAutoCancel(true)
    stopSelf()
```

but still the audio is playing even after i click the notification

what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: you should stop `MediaPlayerManager`, which seems to be a singleton. it isn't tied to `Notification` or `Service` at all, so `setAutoCancel` or `stopSelf` doesn't stopping audio

Comment: you can stop the audio playback in onDestroy() method manually.

Comment: how to assign ".addAction" to a specific id from the custom view? so if the user clicked the textview the audio will stop